# Mudar o Tamanho da caixa do InputQuery

Tags: delphi, delphi-10, delphi-berlin, delphi-tokyo

O `InputQuery` é uma mensagem onde podemos informar um determinado valor, mas alterando o valor da variável passada como referencia, veja sua estrutura :

```
//Função InputQuery 
function InputQuery(const ACaption, APrompt: string;
  var Value: string): Boolean;
```

---

Queria saber se tem alguma maneira de diminuir o tamanho da janela da mensagem do `InputQuery`?

[image: Foto]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esta função não possui um `overload` que disponibilize isto, o jeito é fazer uma.

Tenho diversas prontas em meu sistema para diversos formatos, seja, String, Extended, Integer, Datas etc...

Segue exemplo:

```
function TFormTeste.InputValor(const aCaption: String; var aValor: String): Boolean;
var
  vForm  : TForm;
  vLabel : TLabel;
  vBtnOk : TBitBtn;
  vValor : TEdit;
begin
  Result  := False;
  vForm   := TForm.Create(Application);
  vLabel  := TLabel.Create(vForm);
  vBtnOk  := TBitBtn.Create(vForm);
  vValor  := TEdit.Create(vForm);

  with vForm do
  begin
    Name           := 'FormValor';
    Position       := poScreenCenter;
    BorderIcons    := [biSystemMenu];
    BorderStyle    := bsSingle;
    Caption        := aCaption;
    ClientHeight   := 70;
    ClientWidth    := 180;
    Color          := clBtnFace;
    OldCreateOrder := False;
    PixelsPerInch  := 96;
  end;

  with vLabel do
  begin
    Name    := 'vLabel';
    Parent  := vForm;
    Left    := 8;
    Top     := 16;
    Width   := 31;
    Height  := 13;
    Caption := 'Valor: ';
  end;

  with vValor do
  begin
    Name      := 'vValorEdit';
    Parent    := vForm;
    Left      := 52;
    Top       := 11;
    Width     := 120;
    Height    := 21;
    TabOrder  := 0;
  end;

  with vBtnOk do
  begin
    Name        := 'vBtnOk';
    Parent      := vForm;
    Caption     := 'Ok';
    Left        := vValor.Left;
    Top         := vValor.Top + vValor.Height + 5;
    Width       := vValor.Width;
    Height      := 21;
    ModalResult := mrOk;
  end;

  vForm.ShowModal;

  if(vForm.ModalResult = mrOk) and
    (vValor.Text <> '') then
  begin
    Result := True;
    aValor := vValor.Text;
  end;

  FreeAndNil(vForm);
end;
```

Utilização da mesma forma que a Oficial:

```
var
  vTeste : String;
begin
  if (InputValor('Informe um texto', vTeste) = True) then
    ShowMessage(vTeste);
```

Comment: Opa ! isso é bom... vou testar...

Comment: ta ficando bom to ajeitando para ficar do tamanho que quero. Obrigado!

Comment: Resolvendo o problema, marque a resposta como correta, isso ajuda aos futuros pesquisadores.

Comment: Se colocar outro botão ex: Cancelar como faz para se clicar cancelar tudo?

Comment: Crie um botão = fiz com o OK, e no `ModalResult := mrCancel`, ai você testa no momento de atribuir a variável se o ModalResult foi um Ok

Comment: fiz isso só que ele está funcionando igual ao OK

Comment: Acho que é por conta do ` if (vValor.Text <> '') then
  begin
    Result := True;
    aValor := vValor.Text;
  end;`

Comment: antes do `if (vValor.Text <> '')` coloque: `if ModalResult = MrOk then...`

Comment: não vai,  o ModalResult  fica sempre   = 0

Comment: Editei a resposta, é que você não estava apontando para o `Form`, ai o Result sempre é 0.

Comment: Valeu! Ficou muito bom